# GPU Rendering issue “Cuda error at cuCtxCreate: Illegal Address

Tags: baking, error

I get that error message when I try to bake a simple AO map in cycles. I can do it with cpu but with the gpu i get that error message.

I have 13gig of memory on the card so it cant be that but just to check I tried to bake on a simple cube and got same error.

Any Ideas?

-Computer-
Processor : 12x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz
Memory : 32842MB (5671MB used)
Operating System : Manjaro Linux
Resolution : 1680x1050 pixels
OpenGL Renderer : GeForce GTX TITAN X/PCIe/SSE2
X11 Vendor : (null)

Comment: What version of blender? Are your drivers up to date?

Comment: hey, yeah drivers auto update.
blender version 2.79

Comment: funny thing is I can use gpu to render big scenes, that's why im confused

Comment: What is your OS? I'm using Windows10 64bit and having the same problem I attempting to resolve this now.

Comment: I updated my Nvidia drivers to 391.05 (it's a hotfix) fixed my problem no more errors so far.

Comment: Still getting the error will try something else.

Answer (score 2):

Roll back the Nvidia graphics driver to when it did work properly.

In my case Nvidia drivers to v391.0 caused this error.
Since I don't auto update my drivers I rolled it back to v388.0 and rendered over a 100 frames in full HD with no problems.